# Core Data Migration

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, core-data

My app is using Core Data, and we can make a backup of our data and export them to Dropbox. Then from Dropbox you can import your backups again and this action delete the current data, now the problem is that after adding a new attribute for an entity, I can not import the old model backup because it doesn't have this new attribute, is it possible in some way to import the old model?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just provide a default value for the missing field.

Comment: Thank you !! For someone else with the same problem you have to uncheck the optional field and then provide a default value!

Comment: You an also leave it optional if that suits your model better and insert the default value later in code. - Welcome to stackoverflow. It is customary on this platform to tick the check mark if an answer has helped you.